# Autofill with REST API in windows 8.1 phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am implementing a city search so I want a Autofill with the functionality where when I select a city I want the ID to be sent back to the API. to populate some other fields.

```
 private async void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
            {
                string text = sender.Text;

                if (text.Length >= 3)
                {
                   GetCities(text);
                   sender.ItemsSource = await Task<string[]>.Run(() => { return this.GetSuggestions(text); });
                }
                else
                {
                    sender.ItemsSource = new string[] { "No suggestions..." };
                }
            }
        }
```

My Get response class

```
private async void GetCities(string city)
        {
            try
            {
                string baseAddress = Url.url + "searchCities?q="+city+"&access_token=" + tcm;

                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

                string co = "";
                var content = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(baseAddress));
                if (!content.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    TokenGenerator tc = new TokenGenerator();
                    tc.GetToken();
                    tcm = TokenManager.accessT.access_tocken;

                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    content = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(baseAddress));

                }

                co = await content.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                AutofillHelper result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AutofillHelper>(co);                   
                foreach (var item in result.data)
                {
                   suggestions = new string [] {item.city} ;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }   

private string[] GetSuggestions(string text)
        {
            string[] result = null;

            result = suggestions.Where(x => x.StartsWith(text)).ToArray();

            return result;
        }
```

My Get Set

```
class Autofill
    {            
            public string city_id { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }        

    }


    class AutofillHelper
    {
        public List<Autofill> data { get; set; }             
    }
```

I want it to display the response from the API for the person to select it.  A Run time error is thrown. Can someone please guide me what has gone wrong.

Any kind of help is appreciated...

Comment: Why not download the city list first and inside `AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged` use your query statement to update the ItemSource. Its better than always hitting the API for each character entered

Comment: City list is too large to get it down...

Comment: if the city list is large why not add it using sqlite as a resource instead. Since firing requests for every textchanged aint feasible esp in 2g networks where network loss is an issue.

Comment: Moreover 'suggestions = new string [] {item.city} ;' does it do the required function.Can you place a breakpoint on line `result = suggestions.Where(x => x.StartsWith(text)).ToArray();' and check the value of suggestions if it holds any value or not.

Comment: thank you guys I got it working now but the issue now is 'suggestions = new string [] {item.city} ;' replaces the previous value in the array what can I do ?

Comment: So I was right. Well new string [] {item.city} it creates a new string array instead of appending to existing array list. But adding to array string wont be feasible instead try to use List<string> suggestion. now replace 'suggestions = new string [] {item.city} ;' with `suggestion.Add(item)`. Also make sure you do clear the value of list before API hits else it will keep appending to previous lists